# Query in Spring JPA using List of two parameters

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-repositories, jpa-criteria

```
public interface InventoryRepository extends JPARepository<Inventory, Long> {

List<Inventory> findByIdIn(List<Long> ids);

}
```

Above is working fine, however in same way I am trying to fetch the List or Map, based on multiple params List ids and List sortNumber.

I would be also happy with return type Map from the method.

I came up with below things, which isn't correct.

```
List<Inventory> findByIdANDSortNumberIn(List<Long> ids, List<Long> sortNumbers);
```

Should do it with help of Criteria ? Is there any better way to do it?

Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Constants.T_INVENTROTY)
@Data
public class Inventory implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = Constants.COLUMN_IN_DM)
private Long id;

@Column(name = Constants.COLUMN_PROD_DESCRIPTION)
private String prodDescription;


@Column(name = Constants.COLUMN_PROD_DESCRIPTION)
private Long sortNumber;

@Column(name = Constants.COLUMN_QUANTITY)
private long quantity

}
```

Comment: show your Inventory class

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
List<Inventory> findByIdInAndSortNumberIn(List<Long> ids, List<Long> sortNumbers);
```

You can specify `And` and do the same for multiple fields.

Comment: Tried the same. But throwing Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01797: this operator must be followed by ANY or ALL

Comment: Added in description

Comment: did you try `findByIdInAndSortNumberIn` or `findByIdAndSortNumberIn`. see my answer correctly.